# Display data from QAbstractTableModel in QTreeView

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside

**Short version**

I am trying to display data from a `QAbstracctTableModel` in a `QTreeView`. When I do, I end up with the *entire table* displayed as the child of every node (and grandchild, and so-on). How can I display a treeview of an abstract table model?

**Details**

I am trying to display some data in a `QAbstractTableModel` in a `QTreeView`. In the [Model-View Tutorial](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/modelview.html#3-1-treeview), after presenting an example `QAbstractTableModel`, it makes it seem it's as simple as replacing `QTableView` with `QTreeView`:

> You can convert the example above into an application with a tree
>   view. **Simply replace QTableView with QTreeView**, which results in a
>   read/write tree. No changes have to be made to the model.

When I make this replacement, I do end up with a tree showing, but if I click on any of the icons to expand it (which should do nothing, as there is no hierarchy built in), Python crashes with `Python.exe has stopped working`. This [has been brought up before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25880629/crashing-when-using-qabstracttablemodel-with-qtreeview) ], but without a workable solution.

To try to fix this behavior, I reimplemented the index function in my `QAbstractTableModel` subclass (see full working example below). This leads to a very different type of error. Namely, every node in the tree now contains the entire table as data. No matter how many times I click, the entire table shows up. Like this:

[image: bad tree]

I seem to be in some kind of recursive nightmare, and do not know how to escape. The related question below suggests I might have to go to `QAbstractItemModel`, but the tutorial quote above suggests otherwise (which states, *No changes have to be made to the model*).

**Related question**

[QTreeView always displaying the same data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20577645/qtreeview-always-displaying-the-same-data)

**Full working example**

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class Food(object):
    def __init__(self, name, shortDescription, note, parent = None):
        self.data = (name, shortDescription, note);
        self.parentIndex = parent

class FavoritesTableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self)
        self.foods = []  
        self.loadData() 

    def data(self, index, role = QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self.foods[index.row()].data[index.column()]
        return None

    def rowCount(self, index=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.foods)

    def columnCount(self, index=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 3

    def index(self, row, column, parent = QtCore.QModelIndex()):  
        return self.createIndex(row, column, parent)

    def loadData(self):   
        allFoods=("Apples", "Pears", "Grapes", "Cookies", "Stinkberries")
        allDescs = ("Red", "Green", "Purple", "Yummy", "Huh?")
        allNotes = ("Bought recently", "Kind of delicious", "Weird wine grapes",
                    "So good...eat with milk", "Don't put in your nose")
        for name, shortDescription, note in zip(allFoods, allDescs, allNotes):
            food = Food(name, shortDescription, note)                                      
            self.foods.append(food) 

def main():
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    model = FavoritesTableModel() 

    #Table view
    view1 = QtGui.QTableView()
    view1.setModel(model)
    view1.show()

    #Tree view
    view2 = QtGui.QTreeView()
    view2.setModel(model)
    view2.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [official documentation](http://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/PySide/QtCore/QAbstractItemModel.html#PySide.QtCore.PySide.QtCore.QAbstractItemModel.rowCount):

> When implementing a table based model, `rowCount()` should return 0 when the parent is valid.

The same goes for `columnCount()`. And for completeness, `data()` should return `None` if the parent is valid.

---

What happened is this:

1. You click on the '+' sign next to "Stinkberries".
2. The QTreeView thinks, *"I need to expand the view. I wonder how many rows exist under 'Stinkberries'?"* To find out, the QTreeView calls `rowCount()`, and passes the index of the "Stinkberries" cell as the parent.
3. `FavoritesTableModel::rowCount()` returns 5, so the QTreeView thinks, *"Ah, there are 5 rows under 'Stinkberries'."*
4. The same process happens for columns.
5. The QTreeView decides to retrieve the first item under "Stinkberries". It calls `data()`, passing Row 0, Column 0, and the index of the "Stinkberries" cell as the parent.
6. `FavoritesTableModel::data()` returns "Apples", so the QTreeView thinks, *"Ah, the first item under 'Stinkberries' is 'Apples'."*
7. etc.

To get correct behaviour, your code must return 0 for Steps #3 and #4.

---

Finally, to make sure that the '+' signs don't appear at all, make `hasChildren()` return false for every cell.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'm not sure how to get the right behavior for rowCount, will think about that a bit. Also, do you mean that it should return QVarient() if the parent is *invalid*? Note PySide (which my example is written in) doesn't use `QVariant`, so I edited your answer slightly to include that case. Some code snippets would be very helpful, still getting the hang of turning concepts into code. For instance, I tried (in rowCount) to add : `if (index.parent() == None): return 0` but I still get the same behavior.

Comment: I added `def hasChildren(self, index): return False` but am still getting the + signs.

Comment: Apologies, I was thinking in C++. I don't have PySide (or even Python) experience, but hopefully the PySide behaviours match the original C++ behaviours.

Comment: I definitely meant return 0 (or `None`) if the parent is *valid*.  The reason is this: All top-level items don't have parents; only nested tree items have valid parents. A table model contains no nested items, so all of the items in your model should have no parent. (Please clarify: Which parts of my numbered list do you understand, and which parts don't you understand?)

Comment: I notice you declared `def rowCount(self, index=QtCore.QModelIndex())`. Why did you name the parameter "index"? The parameter actually refers to the parent. (See http://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/PySide/QtCore/QAbstractItemModel.html#PySide.QtCore.PySide.QtCore.QAbstractItemModel.rowCount ) Anyway, the correct code should be `def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()): if (parent != None) return 0 ...`

Comment: I am  such a noob, you are right that's supposed to be parent! I'm at work, will hack at this when I get a free moment later this afternoon, thanks so much...

Comment: Interesting: `def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()): if (parent != QtCore.QModelIndex()): return 0; else: return len(self.foods)` seems to help: when I do that the + signs disappear, suggesting I don't have a bunch of more data hidden under each node (yeah!). It seems `hasChildren` is never called-when I add a print statement therein it is never executed...Will hack at this some more, still sort of confused about how to best implement 'index', and whether my Food class is sufficient, and a ton of other stuff. Will update tomorrow.

Answer (score 4):

**Solution**

In theory, a nice feature of the Model-View framework is that you can have multiple views of the same Model. In practice, though, `QAbstractTableModel` is really meant to help you view tables, not trees. [The documentation](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtCore/QAbstractTableModel.html) for `QAbstractTableModel` says:

> Since the model provides a more specialized interface than
>   QAbstractItemModel, it is not suitable for use with tree views

However, even given that caveat, there is a way to get this to work. First, as pointed out by JKSH, you have to fix `rowCount` (and note that its second parameter is a *parent* index):

```
def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
    if parent.isValid():
        return 0
    return len(self.foods)
```

Second, remove the quixotic reimplementation of `index`, which was making the selection behavior act really weird for reasons I frankly don't understand.

In general, though, if you want a generic model then play it safe and subclass from `QAbstractItemModel` instead of one of the pre-made models.

**Discussion**

Ignoring the parent within `rowCount` is acceptable in table models. In the official Qt book, they follow the standard procedure of having `rowCount` returning solely the number of rows to be displayed in the table. Blanchette and Summerfield note:

> The parent parameter has no meaning for a table model; it is there
>   because rowCount() and columnCount() are inherited from the more
>   generic QAbstractItemModel base class, which supports heirarchies. (p
>   255)

In his PyQt book, Summerfield notes:

> [T]he parent QModelIndex p matters only to tree models (p 434)

Basically, `rowCount` tells you how many rows to display underneath a parent item. Because in tables all items have the same parent, the parent item is not used in `QTableView`s. But for reasons pointed out very nicely by JKSH in his answer, this strategy won't work with trees.

Hence, the claim that the parent parameter "has no meaning for a table model" should be modified with the qualification that *this is only true if the data will exclusively be displayed by a `QTableView`* (which is usually a pretty good assumption).