# How to construct a QModelIndex with valid parent?

Tags: qt

I'm trying to unittest my implementation of QAbstractTableModel. I have implemented rowCount(), columnCount() and data() methods.

After instantiating my model, no matter how many nestings deep, the parent index is always invalid:

```
parent = model->index(0, 0);
i = model->index(0, 0, parent); // i.parent().IsValid() == false!
```

Now, i is valid. But i.parent() is not.
Even if I do further nesting:

```
ancestor = model->index(0, 0);
parent = model->index(0, 0, ancestor);
i = model->index(0, 0, parent); // i.parent().IsValid() == false!
```

even then, i is valid but i.parent() is not.

I have unit tested the rowCount and columnCount methods and I've asserted that the model is a tree model that has one row with, nested, two rows. Also, the column count is nonzero.

Why is my parent index always invalid?

Comment: are you sure you are actually setting `i`s parent?

Comment: If you want to create a tree model, you need to derive from`QAbstractItemModel` not `QAbstractTableModel`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a table. It's not supposed to be a tree. Because of that, the parent will always be invalid. The `QAbstractTableModel::index` implementation always sets an invalid parent, and it's supposed to.

Your expectations apply to a tree model, not a table model. And they only apply to a tree model if the given parent element has children. Your test wrongly assumes that the parent it is using has children, when it has none. You can easily check that: `model->hasChildren(parent)` will always return `false` for a table. Trying to create an index with a childless parent is undefined. Ideally your model should assert on it. Thus, your test would be generally wrong for a tree too.

If you want to implement a tree, derive from `QAbstractItemModel`. You'll then be forced to correctly implement `bool hasChildren(const QModelIndex& parent) const` - that's the method that the tree view (and your tests!) should use to know whether it's valid to request an index for a given parent's child.

Generally speaking, if `model.hasChildren(parent) == false` then you're never supposed to call `model.index(row, col, parent)`. In fact, your model should assert that it is so:

```
QModelIndex MyModel::index(int row, int col, const QModelIndex & parent) {
  Q_ASSERT(hasChildren(parent));
  Q_ASSERT(row >= 0 && row < rowCount(parent));
  Q_ASSERT(col >= 0 && col < columnCount(parent));
  void * ptr = ...; // or quintptr ptr = ...;
  return createIndex(row, col, ptr);
}
```

Comment: Then why is it possible to use a QAbstractTableModel with a QTreeView? (e.g. here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27308309/display-data-from-qabstracttablemodel-in-qtreeview) Doesn't that work on these same assumptions also? Also, the parent I am using does have children, I implemented my data method so that it does. How do you suggest I move forward? Do I override the ::index method?

Comment: A `QTreeView` checks each parent for children, and only attempts to create child indices if the children exist. A tree view is a perfectly valid way to display a table or list model. A table/list model is a tree with just a trunk.

Comment: #1. What's the exact definition of 'child'? I have implemented the data() method such that it inspects the parent() and returns data. That's a child to me. #2. What alternative do I have? I can't find a QAbstractTreeModel.

Comment: A class derived from a `QAbstractTableModel` must be a table. It cannot be a tree. You want to derive from the base class - the `QAbstractItemModel`. You'll have to implement more methods - since these methods were implemented for a table by `QAbstractTableModel`.

Comment: A child is any item that has an index with a valid parent, whose parent must return `hasChildren() == true`. A `QAbstractTableModel` doesn't support such models because it's a table, not a tree.